# Open multiple separately packaged indesign files at once with script

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I feel like I am already really close to making this happen I just need to add another level to it.

So far the code below will open every indesign file in the folder selected when you run the script.

```
var myFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select Indesign Folder");  
var myIndsnFiles = myFolder.getFiles("*.indd");  

for(k=0; k<myIndsnFiles.length; k++)  
{  
    app.open(myIndsnFiles[k]);  

    }
```

So for example lets say the path to this folder that contains multiple indesign files is desktop/ads/client1 but in the ads folder there are multiple folders (client1, client2, client3 etc.) and each one contains an indesign file.

What I want to do is select the ads folder and run the script and have it automatically search each folder and open the indesign files that lie inside.

I hope I explained this well enough to make sense.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did my own recursive function for getting files whatever subfolder they are in…

```js
var api = {
 getFiles : function ( fo, aExtensions, bRecursive, aFiles, includeFolder )
 {
  var exts = aExtensions? aExtensions.join("|") : ".+" ;
  var pattern = new RegExp ( "\\."+exts+"$", "g" );
  var files = aFiles? aFiles : [];
  var filterFunction = function(file)
  {
   return pattern.test ( file.name );
  }
  
  if ( bRecursive )
  {
   var foFiles = fo.getFiles();
   while (  f = foFiles.shift() )
   {
    if ( f instanceof Folder )
    {
     if (includeFolder===true) files[ files.length ] = f;
     
     this.getFiles ( f, aExtensions, true, files );
    }
    if ( f  instanceof File && pattern.test ( f.name ) ) 
    files[ files.length ]  = f;
   }
  
   return files;
  }
 
  else
  {
   return fo.getFiles ( filterFunction );
  }
 },
}

var fo =  Folder.selectDialog(), u, files;
if ( fo ) {
 files = api.getFiles ( fo, ["indd"], true, u, false );
 alert( files.join("\r") );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Works like a champ!